# jQuery make DOM changements inside a dom element

Tags: jquery, dom, this

I have a 4 divs like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how can I explain this but I want to reverse `<h3>` and `<img>` in each 2 `.col` divs. The final content should looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="..." alt="">
        <h3>A title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src="..." alt="">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried several tweaks like `$('.col:odd img').insertAfter( "h3" );` or

```
var myImg = $( "h3" );
$('.col:odd').find( myImg ).insertAfter( "h3" );
```

and a lot of crappy code but didn't managed to find a good way to do this.
My Google/Stackoverflow searches seems to return no good results. I may not have properly searched?

Any clue/idea to do this?

Thank you and sorry for the english :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

1. [`:even`](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector to select alternate element
2. Use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over elements
3. [Context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) to select the elements inside the current element
4. [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to move element after the passed element.

Code:

```
$('.content .col:even').each(function () {
    $('h3', this).insertAfter($('img', this));
});
```

```js
$('.content .col:even').each(function() {
  $('h3', this).insertAfter($('img', this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>A title</h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Another title</h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>A title</h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Another title</h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4/" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first `index` will start from `0` which is not `odd` but op is considering first `index` from `1` which is `odd` .

Comment: I knew I was missing something. I had all elements but I didn't think about `.each()`. Thank you Tushar and thanks too for the "Context selector" doc :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.each($(".col"),function(key,val){
   $($(val).children()[0]).before($($(val).children()[1]));
  });  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Another title</h3>
        <img src="..." alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```